# Using Join Table in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

I want to create a workflow in ModelBuilder. The workflow I work on is this: first I create a fishnet on my land use raster's extent. Then I assign dominant land use classes on every grid as table with majority statistic type in "Zonal Statistics as table". Then I want to join the output table coming from zonal statistics into the empty fishnet (Figures Below). But I could not join together these two different features with "Add Join" command.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Join takes feature layers or table views as inputs. Either convert your  feature classes to feature layers with [Make Feature Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm), or use [Join Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm): this tool will accept a feature class as input.